# Is boundary well defined if variation of metric don't vanish on the boundary?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

Suppose that you want to calculate the variation $\delta S$ of an action induced by some arbitrary variation $\delta g_{\mu \nu}$ of the spacetime metric :
\begin{equation}
S = \int_{\Omega} \mathscr{L} \, \sqrt{- g} \; d^D x.
\end{equation}
The domain of integration $\Omega$ is any finite part of spacetime, and $\partial \, \Omega$ is its boundary.  Usually, $\Omega$ and $\partial \, \Omega$ are fixed during the variation and we're asking that $\delta g_{\mu \nu} = 0$ on $\partial \, \Omega$.

If $\delta g_{\mu \nu} \ne 0$ on $\partial \, \Omega$, does it make sense to talk about a *fixed* boundary in General Relativity ?

If the metric isn't fixed, I'm not sure it make any sense to talk about a given region of spacetime.

I need opinions and/or references on this.

**EDIT :** Take note that the question ***is not*** about any boundary conditions imposed on the hypersurface $\partial \, \Omega$.  Whatever what are the boundary conditions, if you have $\delta g_{\mu \nu} \ne 0$ on $\partial \, \Omega$ (maybe it is the momentum that is fixed, or whatever else), can we still define the boundary ?

I have the feel that the coordinates and boundary are dependent on the metric, in general relativity, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What exactly is a "finite part" of spacetime? Do you mean *compact*? Why are you not sure whether you can talk about the regions without the metric - the region and its boundary are just subsets of the space, they don't change under the metric.

Comment: The [boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29) of a set is just the set-theoretic difference between its closure and its interior, as defined by the topology of the manifold (which is independent of the metric and of chosen coordinates). Well, I guess this is an answer...writing it up.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to clarify.  The finite region $\Omega \subset \mathcal{M}$ is any part of the manifold, which may (or may not) be compact.

Comment: To define the action integral, you need some coordinates (even if it is a scalar, diffeomorphism invariant).  Then how can you define the coordinates of the boundary without the metric ?  I'm not sure that you could erect a system of coordinates without refering to some features of the geometry (i.e. metric and/or curvature).

Comment: @Cham So you're saying something like Stokes' theorem needs a metric to be valid? I'd like for you to find me a standard proof that uses a metric :)

Comment: I don't think that we need a metric to prove Stoke's theorem or Gauss theorem.

Comment: @Cham Exactly, so why do you need it to define the integrals?

Comment: That's a crucial point :  I don't want the boundary to be dependent on the metric!  I want the metric variation to **not vanish** on the boundary, to define another quantity to be fixed there.  As I said as a comment to ACuriousMind's answer, I think that *the Einstein-Hilbert action is better described as a problem with a fixed canonical momentum on the boundary*. If this is true, then we don't need to add any surface counter-term (aka Gibbons-Hawking-York) to the Einstein-Hilbert action ! This view is supported by T. Padmanabhan.  I want to be sure that all this is actually making sense.

Comment: Just like for a scalar field, there are two choices.  The analog of Dirichlet is $\delta g_{\mu\nu} = 0$.  The analog of Neumann goes by another name -- the Israel junction condition.  See for example this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0208205v3.pdf for the Israel junction condition in the presence of an additional Gauss-Bonnet term.  I would refer you to Israel's paper, but it's 50 years old.

Comment: So for a real Klein-Gordon scalar field, the Israel junction condition is $n^{\mu} \, \partial_{\mu} \, \phi = 0$, where $n^{\mu}$ is the normal to the boundary, is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

The [boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29) of a subset of a topological space is abstractly defined as the set-theoretic difference between its closure and its interior. Since topological spaces in general have neither coordinates nor metrics, this notion is independent of the metric.

Since the spacetime manifold is a *manifold*, it is a topological space (locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$) even when not equipped with a metric (and a Lorentzian (pseudo-)metric tensor does not induce a metric topology, contrary to the Riemannian case). Therefore, the notation of a boundary of a subset of $M$ is completely independent of any choice of coordinates or metric, since it purely relies on the topology of the manifold.

Similarly, integration on the manifold does not actually rely on a choice of coordinates, it is abstractly defined by the integration of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) over [chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_%28algebraic_topology%29). Those objects are almost always used in some particular coordinate system by physicists, but the differential geometric objects described by them are coordinate-independent: Every choice of coordinates will yield the same result for invariant quantities such as the value of an integral.

In this specific case, the Lagrangian is just a function of fields, which are in turn functions of the manifold, and if it is properly coordinate-invariant (which it should be!), then multiplying it by the volume form provided by the metric and integrating the entire thing over a spacetime volume is coordinate-invariant, too.

Comment: I agree with this.  But then, to define the action integral, you need to set up some coordinates (even if the lagrangian is a scalar, i.e. invariant under coordinates reparametrizations).  Then how can we define any coordinates without reference to some features of the geometry (i.e. without a metric and/or curvature) ?  In the case of a flat manifold (Minkowski spacetime), we could define a set of global cartesian coordinates, but then we already know the metric.

Comment: @Cham: I don't understand your problem: You define the coordinate-invariant (but metric-dependent) volume form $\omega(g) = \sqrt{\det(g)}\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^n$. You take the form $\mathscr{L}[\phi_i,g]\omega(g)$, which is field- and metric-dependent, and define the coordinate-invariant, but field- and metric dependent integral $S[\phi_i,g] := \int_\Omega \mathscr{L}[\phi_i,g]\omega(g)$ where $\Omega$ is any $n$-chain (another coordinate-invariant notion). Everything is coordinate-invariant, what is the problem?

Comment: I understand all this.  But can we define a coordinate system covering a patch of the manifold, without any reference to the metric ?

Comment: @Cham: Of course. That's possible *by definition of a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)* - a manifold is an object that can be covered by coordinate patches, but a generic manifold doesn't have a metric at all.

Comment: Hmmm, yep, this is true.  Then my confusion comes from something else.  So you're saying that **we can** define a variation $\delta g_{\mu \nu}$ that **do not vanish** on the boundary, is that right ?

Comment: @Cham: Yes, there is no problem in *having* a variation on the boundary. I'm not sure whether or not that is physically meaningful, though, probably depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: It's because I want to define some other quantity to be fixed on the boundary, instead of the metric.  Usually, everybody fixes the metric on $\partial \, \Omega$.  I think that the *Einstein-Hilbert action is better described as a problem with a fixed **canonical momentum** on the boundary*.  If this is true, then we don't need to add any surface counter term (Gibbons-Hawking-York) to the Einstein-Hilbert action !  This view is supported by T. Padmanabhan.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with saying that we have a region with boundary as far as the underlying manifold goes. The problem is that you don't know the metric on the boundary or how to integrate. You should rephrase your question accordingly and in that case yes you need to be careful what boundary conditions you take as already said.

Comment: Please, could you elaborate ?  The question is how can we define the coordinates and the boundary without a metric.  Or does it make sense to talk about a boundary if you don't already know the metric ? (whatever the boundary conditions you impose on the said boundary)

Comment: ACuriousMind has done so.

Comment: In what way do you need to be careful with the boundary conditions ?  It is not related to the question, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following action:
$$
\begin{equation}
S = \int_{\Omega} \mathscr{L} \, \sqrt{- g} \; d^D x
\end{equation}
$$
Let's apply a local transformation on $g_{ab}$ and $x^{\mu}$, only in the boundary $\partial \Omega$.
$$\delta g_{ab}=Y_{ab}(...)\epsilon (x)$$
$$\delta x^{\mu}=X^{\mu}(...)\epsilon (x)$$
Where $X^{\mu}$ and $Y_{ab}$ are functions of the fields, metric and space. With a little bit of work (I'm letting as an exercise) you get this variation on the boundary:
$$
\begin{equation}
\delta S = \int_{\partial \Omega} \left[\mathscr{L} \, \sqrt{- g} \;\delta x^{\mu}\;+\;\frac{\partial \left(\mathscr{L} \, \sqrt{- g} \right)}{\partial \left(\partial _{\mu} g_{ab}\right)}\delta_0 g_{ab} \right]  \; ds_{\mu}
\end{equation}
$$
Here $\delta _0$ means vertical variations: $\delta_{0}=\delta - \delta x^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$. Note that $\delta x_{\mu}$ contain is variation over the manifold (here only in the boundary since we are integrating only in the boundary). Fixing the boundary is simply taking $X^{\mu}=0$. Then: 
$$
\begin{equation}
\delta S = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial \left(\mathscr{L} \, \sqrt{- g} \right)}{\partial \left(\partial _{\mu} g_{ab}\right)}\delta g_{ab}\; ds_{\mu}
\end{equation}
$$
So, you have boundary terms of the variation of the metric only if the lagrangian has some $\partial_{\mu}g_{ab}$ term. Then, if you have some dynamical role for the metric you may have this boundary term that are related with things getting "in and out" of the region of space-time mapped by $\Omega$, or at least a topological counter one. Note that $\Omega$ here is simple a set of events and don't have any geometrical notion.

Answer (score -1):

It does not make sense to have $\delta g_{\mu \nu}\neq 0$. Actually, for finite region, even if the variation of metric is zero at boundary, the derivative of metric is not zero, it will contribute a surface term to the variation of actio,  thus we have to add another surface term to cancel this contribution, which consists of exterior curvature of the boundary. The term originally comes from Hawking, Carters' paper on black hole thermodynamics.

Comment: You still can apply the stationary action principle with a variation $\delta g_{\mu \nu}$ of ***compact support***, for which $\delta g_{\mu \nu} = 0$ ***and*** $\partial_{\lambda} \, \delta g_{\mu \nu} = 0$ on the boundary.  This is actually a well known procedure to get the equation in the bulk.  You don't need any boundary conditions and surface terms for this.  And if you do take the boundary conditions, you're not necessarily constrained with $\delta q = 0$ (Dirichlet) at the boundary.  Other quantities may be fixed at the boundary (ex : momenta).  So it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In order to obtain the equation of motion in the bulk, of course you can just handle the boundary by letting $g_{\mu\nu}=0=\partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu\nu}$, in other word, you just ignore the surface term when you do the variation. But sometimes, you cannot do the procedure because the action itself is important to you, for example, when you do path integral.  Then the procedure you take is obviously wrong, because making $\partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu\nu}$ at boundary means that you do not integrate over all possible path.

Comment: Why it doesn't make sense to have $\delta g_{\mu \nu} \ne 0$ on $\partial \, \Omega$ ?  Depending on the boundary conditions, it may be that it isn't the metric that is fixed, it may be something else.  Maybe it is preferable to fix a *combination* of $g_{\mu \nu}$ and $\partial_{\lambda} \, g_{\mu \nu}$ on the boundary (like canonical momentum).  According to T. Padmanabhan, it may be *better to describe the Einstein-Hilbert action as a problem with a fixed canonical momentum on the boundary*.

Comment: For a given boundary, it implies(or means) that the induced metric on the boundary if fixed. If you don't have $\delta_{\mu\nu}=0$, then you cannot fix the induced metric on the boundary.

Comment: That is not clear.  It may be related to what I'm asking :  does the boundary depends or not on the metric.  According to the other answers, it doesn't.  So the boundary's normal doesn't depend on the metric neither.  There's no "induced metric" in this case.  Your answer is in conflict with some of the other answers.  **See ACuriousMind's answer and his comments below it.**

Comment: and why would you want to fix the induced metric ?  If $\delta g_{\mu \nu} \ne 0$ on $\partial \, \Omega$, it's because something else is fixed (like the canonical momentum, for example).  Where's the problem with that ?

Answer (score -1):

The question is why you would want to do this in the first place. The equations of motion that you obtain one a compact region still aren't the real equations of motion, since the compact region is a mathematical choice to simplify the formulation of the problem. It is implicitly understood that the true equations of motion are only obtained on the limit of this region becoming very large or infinite

Comment: I don't agree with this.  There are only one set of equations of motion ; i.e. the same whatever the bulk region you take, be it finite or infinite.  Or show us an example of equations that aren't the same (i.e. that change because you don't have an infinite bulk).  Your answer doesn't make sense !

Comment: The equations of motion happen to have the same form for any shape of the domain, even while the domain of variation is different. Which is the reason why you don't need to actually do anything to take the limit, the same reason why it is useful to only consider a finite region, and why considering variations in a finite boundary is entirely pointless

Comment: It doesn't make any sense !  You are contradicting yourself, when you say (from your answer) : *"The equations of motion that you obtain one a compact region still aren't the real equations of motion"*.